# jQuery: fire "mouseout" only when the user moves their mouse out of the container?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a parent div with two inner divs, part of a Google Maps OverlayView:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="inner1">inner 1</div>
    <div id="inner2">inner2</div>
</div>
```

I want to fire a `mouseout` event only when the user moves their mouse outside the boundaries of `#container`. At the moment I have this code:

```
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(this.$content.get(0), "mouseout", function (e) {
      console.log('InfoWindow mouseleave', $(e.fromElement));
    });
```

But it's firing whenever the user moves their mouse into `#inner1` too. In fact, looking at `e.fromElement`, it seems to fire whenever the user moves their mouse into the container! What can I do?

The correct answer in jQuery seems to be to use the mouseleave event, but I **don't appear to have access to that in Google Maps** - at least, if I change mouseout to mouseleave, the event no longer fires at all.

This jsFiddle demonstrates the basic problem: http://jsfiddle.net/pvB4u/1/

Comment: Why don't you use jQuery alone to handle the divs then? As long as gmaps isn't using an iframe then the divs are accessible?

Comment: Have you got an example where we can test it not working, as mouseleave should work?

Comment: Use "mouseleave" event instead "mouseout"

Answer (score 0):

If its not working, you can try alternative. get pageX and pageY for mouse pointer(need to initialize it in document.ready(). Then check if it is inside the boundries of the outermost container. 
 Something like this

```
$(document).mousemove(function (e) {                        

                            if ($("#container").offset().left > e.pageX || (parseInt($("#container").offset().left) + $("#container").width()) < e.pageX
                        || $("#container").offset().top > e.pageY || (parseInt($("#container").offset().top) + $("#container).height()) < e.pageY) {
                                // This will be your required mouseout event
                            }

                    });
```